# Display full width tab underline in syncfusion angular

Tags: html, css, angular, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

I am using syncfusion angular for UI in our application i am stucked with some UI thing . I need to display full width underline tabs like show in below image.

[image]

But i can only develop like this.
[image]

i need to display that tab underline full width like shown in first picture. please help me with this.

- syncfusion html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="#0d6efd" class="bi bi-arrow-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M15 8a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H2.707l3.147-3.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708-.708l-4 4a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708l4 4a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L2.707 8.5H14.5A.5.5 0 0 0 15 8z"/>
        </svg> Back to Previous </p>
      </div>    
      <div class="col-sm-12" >
        <ejs-tab #tab id="element" heightAdjustMode='Auto' overflowMode='popup' (selected)='onTabSelect($event)'
          [selectedItem]="item" >
          <e-tabitems>
              <e-tabitem [header]='headerText[0]' ></e-tabitem>
              <e-tabitem [header]='headerText[1]'></e-tabitem>
              <e-tabitem [header]='headerText[2]'></e-tabitem>
              <e-tabitem [header]='headerText[3]'></e-tabitem>
              <e-tabitem [header]='headerText[4]'></e-tabitem>
              <e-tabitem [header]='headerText[5]'></e-tabitem>
              <e-tabitem [header]='headerText[6]'></e-tabitem>
              <e-tabitem [header]='headerText[7]'></e-tabitem>
              <e-tabitem [header]='headerText[8]'></e-tabitem>
          </e-tabitems>
        </ejs-tab>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `border-bottom` to "Back to previous" div?

```html
<div class="col-sm-4" style="border-bottom: 2px solid gray">
```

Comment: with this i can only show line on left side but tab with is still same

Comment: Please reproduce the problem online (e.g StackBlitz) so we can pinpoint the exact element which should modified.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to show full tab underline for tabs using property (or) methods. Also, we have prepared sample to replicate your issue based on the shared snippets. But, custom element and tab not rendered in same row.

Can you please share the below details which will help us to provide
solution using customized style if possible?

- Replicate the issue in below sample (or) share issue replicating
  sample if possible
- Share all the style related code snippets

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tab-full-width?file=app.component.html